# PowerShell regex to extract SID from filename

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell

I have an array $vhdlist with contents similar to the following filenames:

```
UVHD-S-1-5-21-8746256374-654813465-374012747-4533.vhdx
UVHD-S-1-5-21-8746256374-654813465-374012747-6175.vhdx
UVHD-S-1-5-21-8746256374-654813465-374012747-8147.vhdx
UVHD-template.vhdx
```

I want to use a regex and be left with an array containing only SID portion of the filenames.

I am using the following:

```
$sids = foreach ($file in $vhdlist) 
{
[regex]::split($file, '^UVHD-(?:([(\d)(\w)-]+)).vhdx$')
}
```

There are 2 problems with this: in the resulting array there are 3 blank lines for every SID; and the "template" filename matches (the resulting line in the output is just "template"). How can I get an array of SIDs as the output and not include the "template" line?

Comment: I suspect the regex you want is `^UVHD-\w+(?:-\w+)+\.vhdx$`, and you do not need to split, but match.

Comment: Character classes do not work this way. They are *lists of characters*, i.e. they have no internal structure. That means, `[(\d)(\w)-]` and `[)(\d\w-]` are the same thing.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, that does not work unfortunately. It captures the entire filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to *filter* the list down to those filenames that contain an SID. Filtering is done with `Where-Object` (`where` for short); you don't need a loop.

An SID could be described as *"`S-` and then a bunch of digits and dashes"* for this simple case. That leaves us with `^UVHD-S-[\d-]*\.vhdx$` for the filename.

In combination we get:

```
$vhdlist | where { $_ -Match "^UVHD-S-[\d-]*\.vhdx$" }
```

---

When you don't really have an array of strings, but actually an array of *files*, use them directly.

```
dir C:\some\folder | where { $_.Name -Match "^UVHD-S-[\d-]*\.vhdx$" }
```

Or, possibly you can even make it as simple as:

```
dir C:\some\folder\UVHD-S-*.vhdx
```

---

EDIT

Extracting the SIDs from a list of strings can be thought as a combined *transformation* (for each element, extract the SID) and *filter* (remove non-matches) operation.

PowerShell's `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (`foreach` for short) works like `map()` in other languages. It takes every input element and returns a new value. In effect it transforms a list of input elements into output elements. Together with the `-replace` operator you can extract SIDs this way.

```
$vhdlist | foreach { $_ -replace ^(?:UVHD-(S-[\d-]*)\.vhdx|.*)$,"`$1" } | where { $_ -gt "" }
```

<sup>The regex back-reference for .NET languages is `$1`. The `$` is a special character in PowerShell strings, so it needs to be escaped, except when there is no ambiguity. The backtick is the PS escape character. You can escape the `$` in the regex as well, but there it's not necessary.</sup>

As a final step we use `where` to remove empty strings (i.e. non-matches). Doing it this way around means we only need to apply the regex once, instead of two times when filtering first and replacing second.

PowerShell operators can also work on lists directly. So the above could even be shortened:

```
$vhdlist -replace "^UVHD-(S-[\d-]*)\.vhdx$","`$1" | where { $_ -gt "" }
```

The shorter version only works on lists of actual strings or objects that produce the right thing when `.ToString()` is called on them.

Regex breakdown:

```
^                       # start-of-string anchor
(?:                     # begin non-capturing group (either...)
  UVHD-                 #   'UVHD-'
  (                     #   begin group 1
    S-[\d-]*            #     'S-' and however many digits and dashes
  )                     #   end group 1
  \.vhdx                #   '.vhdx'
  |                     #    ...or...
  .*                    #   anything else
)                       # end non-capturing group
$                       # end-of-string anchor
```

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, but I think you've misunderstood what I'm trying to achieve. I don't want to filter the list, or be left with an array of files. Rather I want to be left with an array of SIDs in string form. I want to remove the portions of the filenames that do not form part of the SIDs.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Transforming a list of things is done with `foreach`. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. This works except that the output still includes the "UVHD-template.vhdx" line, in its entirety, while the other lines include the SID only. I cannot work out why this is happening as i can see that the capturing group should match only a digit or a dash, not alphabetic characters. regexpal.com indicates that the last line should not match. Maybe this is some quirk of PowerShell?

Comment: No, that's because the regex does not properly cover the "not found" case. The regex should be `^(?:UVHD-(S-[\d-]*)\.vhdx|.*)$`, which includes a `.*` alternative as a fallback, for cases where there is no SID.

Comment: That's fixed, and I've added a regex breakdown to the answer as well.